# Angular. Prepend element to body, change from controller to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-controller

I'm doing a gallery in angular and this gallery has a light-box view that shows the image with a dark background when a gallery item is clicked.

Right now I have code inside a **controller** that does the trick like this:

```
$scope.modal = function (iElement) {
    var darkDiv = angular.element('<div class="modal__dark-background"></div>');
    var body = angular.element(document).find('body');
    var overlay = $compile(darkDiv)($scope);
    body.prepend(overlay);
}
```

I also have a directive to insert my main template in a custom element:

```
myApp.directive('gallery', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'partials/gallery.template.html'
    }
})
```

My problem is that I don't know how to make a directive that has the functionality of the code inside the controller. I want to do this because I was toll that is never a good idea to put DOM-related code inside a controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to comment, unfortunately.

> But I don't know how to do **this** for the case of the modal element.

Do what exactly? Do you want to have the directive execute the above code? Try this:

```
myApp.directive('gallery', function($scope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'partials/gallery.template.html',
        controller: function(){
            $scope.modal = ...
        }
    }
})
```

Also I would consider using ui.bootstrap or something similar for tasks like this.

Comment: Is not exactly what I was looking for but It lead me to the right path. Thanks!